# Filtering a list according to information in xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, filtering

I have a list of Model objects and an xml containing information according to which the list should be filtered. I need a filter method that takes the list and xml and returns the filtered list. I need it to be generic so it can handle a list of i.e. ProductModel or a list of CustomerModel. The xml can have `<descriptor>` elements or `<composite>` elements as shown below. The `FilterCompositionLogicalOperator` attribute indicates whether it's logical `AND` or logical `OR` operation. `FilterOperator` represents an Enum for eksample `IsEqualTo = 0` `IsLessThan=1` etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<advanced FilterCompositionLogicalOperator="1">
  <descriptor IsCaseSensitive="false" Member="SalesPrice" MemberType="System.Decimal" FilterOperator="5">800</descriptor>
  <descriptor IsCaseSensitive="false" Member="CostPrice" MemberType="System.Decimal" FilterOperator="5">300</descriptor>
  <composite FilterCompositionLogicalOperator="0">
    <descriptor IsCaseSensitive="false" Member="CostPrice" MemberType="System.Decimal" FilterOperator="5">150</descriptor>
    <descriptor IsCaseSensitive="false" Member="ProductId" MemberType="System.String" FilterOperator="0">400</descriptor>
  </composite>
</advanced>
```

I have tried something like this:

```
    public List<IAdvancedFilterable> HandleXML(XElement xml, IEnumerable<IAdvancedFilterable> filterableList)
    {
      foreach (XElement element in xml.Elements())
      {
        // if composite, I call the method recursively giving it the composite element and list
        // else I read all the attributes of the <descriptor> element. decide the type of the elementValue
        // and then I call helper method 'Filter'

        filtered = Filter(compareOpr, colNameAtt.Value, elementValue, list);

        // Which filters the list according to this <descriptor> element using LINQ.
      }

      return filtered;
    }
```

How to handle the OR situation. AND is easy - you just filter according to each `<descriptor>` and it will be good without any further consideration.

The Filter helper method switches on `FilterOperator` and does for example:

```
    case FilterOperator.IsLessThan:
                if (elementValue.IsInt())
                    return list.Where(d => Convert.ToInt32(d.Source.GetColumnValue(columnName)) < Convert.ToInt32(elementValue));

                if (elementValue.IsDecimal())
                    return list.Where(d => Convert.ToDecimal(d.Source.GetColumnValue(columnName)) < Convert.ToDecimal(elementValue));
                break;
```

My model objects have a method `GetColumnValue(columnName)` that takes a columnName and returns its value.

Any idea how to achieve this effectively? Is LINQ Performant in this situation? Are there better alternatives in order to gain better performance?

Comment: If I were you I would use your Xml to build an expression that you use in the Where clause. This might be useful http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: What is the definition of `IAdvancedFilterable`?

Comment: `IAdvancedFilterable` is just an interface that my Model objects implement. That way I can handle them generically. It exposes a property `Source` that gives access to properties and public methods of the actual model.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can go following way:

1. Create an interface IFilter with a method: `bool Evaluate(XElement element)`
2. Implement 2 classes: `Filter` and `CompositeFilter`.

   a. `CompositeFilter` should have a List of child filters and a flag indicating whether it is AND or OR condition. `Evaluate` method implementation should evaluate all the child filters and return the logical composition of the results, based on AND/OR flag

   ```
   class CompositeFilter {
       bool IsANDCondition; // if false, it is OR;
       List<IFilter> childFilters;
       bool Evaluate(XElement element) {
           bool result = IsANDCondition;
           foreach (var filter in childFilters)
           {
               bool b = filter.Evaluate(element);
               if (IsANDCondition)
                   result = b && result;
               else
                   result = b || result;
           }
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```

   b. `Filter` should have all possible properties (IsCaseSensitive, Member, MemberType, etc.) and implement the logic in the Evaluate method

This way you will have a recursively computed predicate, which you can easily apply to your records:

```
CompositeFilter filter;
var fiteredRecords = records.Where(x=>filter.Evaluate(x));
```